# How do i formulate the following equation as constraint in Gurobi

Tags: optimization, gurobi

I am trying to create a Constraint in Gurobi based on the following formula in python, but don't know how to, any idea??

Sum ( WorkDay (J to J3) + DayOff (J4) + WorkDay (J5)) <= 5

- J is a particular day within any month

--

--

--

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose we start with the data;

```
# Data
workdays = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5]  # (or whatever work days data you have)
days_off = [4]  # (or whatever day off data you have)
days = workdays + days_off
```

Then first you need to create a model

```
from gurobipy import Model

model = Model()
```

And then variables for each day within in, this is assuming that each day is a variable which takes a value meaning that you can choose to do it or how much of it to do.

```
# Variables
day_vars = {
    day: model.addVar()
    for day in days
}
```

Then you want to add a constraint using `model.addConstr` and sum your variables using `quicksum`, for example

```
from gurobipy import quicksum

# Constraints
model.addConstr(
    (
        quicksum(
            day_vars[workday]
            for workday in workdays
        ) + quicksum(
            day_vars[day_off]
            for day_off in days_off
        )
    ) <= 5
)
```

Hope that helps!